# Error while installing pymssql in termux emulator/Kali Linux

Tags: pymssql, termux, termux-linux

error: subprocess-exited-with-error

× Building wheel for pymssql (pyproject.toml) did not run successfully.

│ exit code: 1

╰─> [22 lines of output]

```
  setup.py: platform.system() => Linux

  setup.py: platform.architecture() => ('64bit', 'ELF')

  setup.py: platform.libc_ver() => ('glibc', '2.35')

  setup.py: include_dirs => []

  setup.py: library_dirs => []

  running bdist_wheel

  running build

  running build_py

  creating build

  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.10

  creating build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.10/pymssql

  copying src/pymssql/__init__.py -> build/lib.linux-aarch64-3.10/pymssql

  running build_ext

  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.10

  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.10/src

  creating build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.10/src/pymssql

  aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc -Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -O2 -Wall -g -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -g -fwrapv -O2 -I/opt/homebrew/Cellar/freetds/1.3.3/include -fPIC -I/usr/include/python3.10 -c src/pymssql/_mssql.c -o build/temp.linux-aarch64-3.10/src/pymssql/_mssql.o -DMSDBLIB

  src/pymssql/_mssql.c:751:10: fatal error: sqlfront.h: No such file or directory

    751 | #include "sqlfront.h"

        |          ^~~~~~~~~~~~

  compilation terminated.

  error: command '/bin/aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc' failed with exit code 1

  [end of output]
```

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

ERROR: Failed building wheel for pymssql

Failed to build pymssql

ERROR: Could not build wheels for pymssql, which is required to install pyproject.toml-based project